# Interface Similar to Snapchat with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to get a camera to display on a scroll view much like snapchat does with their swiping navigation.  I have tried to set it up like below where I create an array of the objects to be displayed with the camera being one of them and then set that as the subview of my scroller.  This code works without bugs however nothing is displayed on the screen.  Can anyone help me see what I might be doing wrong.  I think it might be the adding of the subviews.  Should I use a page view instead?  Has anyone attempted to make a UI similar to snapchat's and can offer some links?  Thank you

```
//Set Up the Camera View
    [[self captureManager] addVideoInput];

    [[self captureManager] addVideoPreviewLayer];
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                                  CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    UIView *captureView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [[captureView layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];

    [[captureManager captureSession] startRunning];


    int PageCount = 2;
    NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,captureView,nil];
    UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scroller.bounces = NO;
    scroller.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
    int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
    int xPos=0;
    for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
    {
        UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
        UIView *view2 = [arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
        [view1 addSubview:view2];
        [scroller addSubview:view1];
        scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
        width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should add screenshots of the interface in question, since many of us aren't snapchat users.

Comment: Why do you use an array and the loop to add the two other views?  Where is PageCount set?  And why do you need to enclose the other views in view1 before adding to the scrollView?

Comment: Well I am trying to achieve a view that you can swipe left and right and one of the screens would include a camera.  I'm not entirely sure that I am doing this correctly and am open to completely redoing it.  I thought id need to enclose the views to be able to swipe between them

Answer (score 1):

Use this as an example of how to multiple pages in a page controller:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080